Composition function of log-concave function
Suppose $f(x)$ is log-concave. And $g(x)$ is positive, decreasing and convex.
Do we have any concave/convex conclusion regarding to $g(f(x))$?
Seems that I can show that it is quasi-convex since $f(x)$ is log-concave, so it is quasi-concave. And $-g()$ is a monotone transformation such that $-g(f(x))$ is quasi-concave, too. So $g(f(x))$ is quasi-convex. Correct?
But to have the above conclusion, I only use the information that $g()$ is decreasing.
So is there anything stronger I can get?
